# Jasper report margins larger than what is set

Tags: printing, jasper-reports, margins

I have a jasper report set to portrait letter, which, in pixel terms, translates to 612 x 792 in iReport.  I have the left margin set to 17 pixels and the right set to 10.  That leaves the single column width at 585 with no spacing.

Now, I have two vertical lines that are used to form the report's border, and they're positioned at x-coordinates 0 (for the left bar) and 585 (for the right).  When this reported is executed, the resultant PDF looks perfectly fine.  However, when I go to print, the two vertical lines are missing, and I have to select shrink to fit (which sets the zoom to 94% and displays everything).

I've done some experimenting, and, without shrinking the report at print time, the vertical lines need to be positioned at x-coordinates 2 (for the left) and 575 (for the right) in order to display, which translates into essentially an x-margin of 19 pixels.  Playing around some more, if I set the left margin to 19, the left vertical bar displays at print time when positioned at x-coordinate 0.

Is something else setting the margins at 19 pixels aside from the jasper report itself?  I can't find any culprits in the report itself that seem to be responsible for the discrepancy.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most printers can't print up to the edge of a page.  It sounds like you are hitting this limit.  The print driver is detecting that the PDF doesn't fit inside the printer's printable area and allows you to shrink the content to fit what the printer supports.

Comment: Thanks for the response; that seems to be the issue.  I ended up changing the x-margins to 20px and it seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess. In my reports I use the Background-Band in iReport and draw a rectangle for the background of my reports.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm also using the background band for the vertical bars.